# Multiclass Text Classification in Python

Tags: python, text-classification, multiclass-classification

I am trying to create a Multiclass Text Classifier as explained [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-label-text-classification-with-scikit-learn-30714b7819c5). However, my code is breaking at line:

```
NB_pipeline.fit(X_train, train[category])
```

Below is the error which I am getting:

```
File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 683, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12322)
```

I tried to find out what `train[category]` returns and I got same error.

1) `X_train` is a `dataframe` with one column and contains customer feedback.

2) `train` is a `dataframe` with two columns; first column contains customer review(same as `X_train`) and second column contains one of the 5 categories (`Systems Error, Proactive Communication, Staff Behaviour, Website Functionalities, Others`).

3) `category` is one of the above mentioned categories.

Below is the sample train `dataframe`:

```
Index           Feedback                                    Category
  0           While making payment got system error.         System error
              Staff behaviour was good at hotel

  1           While making payment got system error.         Staff Behaviour
              Staff behaviour was good at hotel
```

Comment: Can you include more of the stack trace and also include the minimal code in the question please. It should be self-contained and reproducible without following a separate website. But strip anything not relevant to the question (but is still reproducible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the most over-looked issue.

The reason for this error is that the "column" script is looking for is not available in the dataframe. All the 5 categories you have, should be columns in the input dataframe and rows will take 1/0 if one of the categories is applicable for the feedback/comment. Ideally, Your input dataframe should look like this.

```
Index           Feedback                                  System error    Staff Behaviour
  0           While making payment got system error.         1                  1
              Staff behaviour was good at hotel

  1           While making payment got system error.         1                  0

  2           Staff behaviour was good at hotel              0                  1
```

I have used same comment to show how input dataframe should look like.

Comment: user7467529: Thank you posting your answer. A well deserved repution loss for me. :P